# Move noscript message

Tags: javascript, css, noscript

I am using the following Javascript noscript message on my website for when a user has his JS disabled:

```
<noscript>

 For full functionality of this site it is necessary to enable <b>JavaScript</b>.
 Here are the <a href="http://www.enable-javascript.com/" target="_blank">
 instructions how to enable JavaScript in your web browser</a>.

</noscript>
```

**My Question:**

It is currently at the absolute top of the window. I would like to move it down to say top:20px...

I tried wrapping the text inside a div that has an offset from the top, but only the text moves along with the div and not the red border styling applied by the `noscript` tag (I did not apply any styling to the `noscript`, it has its own borders)

Comment: Can you add that actual code? You probably have an issue with the relative parent.

Comment: That is the code. This code is included in the head, and not in the body, and it has no css applied to it, but I want it to move down.

Comment: Move it to inside `body`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CSS:

```
noscript
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but for some reason this does not work, at least in my IE9 browser